# DAX ALLEXCEPT: How to remove all filters but one?

Tags: dax

In my simple table, I have 3 columns:

- Date
- Sales
- Store

These are the numbers:
[image]

I want to calculate the sales for all the years for each store:

```
All Except Store = SUMX(ALLEXCEPT(Table1;Table1[Store]);Table1[Sales])
```

This is returning the following:
[image]

It's nonsense! It's removing ALL the filters, so how do I calculate the sales for all the years and KEEP the filters on the store using ALLEXCEPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try structuring your measure like this:

```
All Except Store = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Sales] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Store] ) )
```

Comment: Sure, that works, but why doesn't it work with SUMX?

Comment: The only way you can change the filter context in DAX is with CALCULATE function

Comment: Hey @NunoNogueira, still need further detail on this one?